# @output emittor not working in context menu Angular

Tags: angular

I followed https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event but looks like the emitter is not working. It's not triggering inside the parent component. Does anyone know what's wrong here and how can I fix this?

```html
<div *ngIf="contextmenu">
  <app-contextmenu
    id="child"
    [childMessage]="parentMessage"
    [x]="contextmenuX"
    [y]="contextmenuY"
    (click)="disableContextMenu()"
    (boundStatusUpdated)="getNewScripts($event)"
  ></app-contextmenu>
</div>
```

child component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contextmenu',
})
export class ContextmenuComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() childMessage: string;
  @Input() x = -1;
  @Input() y = -10;

  @Output() boundStatusUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor(
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  HandleBindJson(): void {
      this.updateStatus();
  }

  HandleUnBindJson(): void {
      this.updateStatus();
  }
  updateStatus() {
    this.boundStatusUpdated.emit("updated");
  }
}
```

Here HandleUnBindJson() is called when user clicks on unbind in the context menu. HandleBindJson() is triggered when user selects bind from the context menu and submits a form.
I want to trigger the function getAllScripts() which is in the parent component after the HandleUnBindJson() or HandleBindJson() is function calls are completed.

```js
getNewScripts(event: string) {
  console.log("updated")
  this.getAllScripts();
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't tell if updateStatus is called?

Comment: where is `success` being set? Looks like you are trying to do something a bit off with that considering it doesn't refer to anything in local scope or on the `this` context of the component.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen I just used it to denote that on a success condition the updateStatus() method will be called.

Comment: @AakashGarg its called when  HandleUnBindJson() or  HandleBindJson() is called.  Those function calls work properly. I have edited out the qution explaining about this. Sorry for not explaining it well earlier.

Comment: you sure that updateStatus is getting called?

Comment: @AakashGarg Yes it's getting called. I just added a console.log inside updateStatus to check if its working and it worked

Comment: @AakashGarg but the getNewScripts is not getting called.

Comment: @MaryamYumna add the component that has this method and also it's own template